# Voltage Nominal range vs Maximal range

Tags: voltage

I have a printer , that has this specification about operating voltage :

**Nominal Voltage Range : 100-250 VAC**

**Maximal Voltage Range : 90-264 VAC.**

I need to know the difference between Nominal and maximal ranges , and also that this device will function correctly if voltage goes for example to 260VAC ?

P.s
( I've made this question , because sometimes on my electrical grid , there are changes of the voltage during a day , between 200-260 VAC ? And the AWR protection devices that operate within the Europian standards says that if the voltage is 230+/- 10% , this is normal and need no regulation ).

Answer (score 1):

- Your printer is **designed** for voltages between 100 and 250 VAC. This is the **nominal** voltage range.
- Tolerances and safety margins will keep your printer working between 90 and 264 VAC. This is the **maximal** voltage range.

Your printer will keep working at 260 VAC, any voltages higher than this will most likely trip safety measures inside the printer that may or may not be reset by unplugging and waiting (polyfuses, surge protection, etc.). The latter features a highly dependant on the build quality.

Comment: Thank you friend , but by the way , i have my Pc and other devices . But for Pc's power supply for example , i don't know these voltage ranges. Is it true that these days all the devices  produced for Europe , can operate within Europen standarts , 230 V +/- 10% ?

Comment: They should as long as they are not intended to be export only devices.

Comment: Laptop's power supplies for examples , even in these days have the 100-240 VAC limit . So these are not in the European standard ranges ???

Comment: The 100-240 VAC rating is the **nominal** rating. Most of them will survive 255 VAC without problems, they will not be harmful to the user, as they will have to obey many safety standards as well.

Comment: Just to add, the nominal range is what the printer is designed to operate in.  The maximum is transient conditions the printer can tolerate.  The printer isn't designed to operate for extended periods outside of the nominal range.